# Is it necessary to initialize COM when using ShellExecute()?

Tags: c, winapi, com

Can I use `ShellExecute()` without initializing COM first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153.aspx) has the answer to your question:

> Because ShellExecute can delegate execution to Shell extensions (data
>   sources, context menu handlers, verb implementations) that are
>   activated using Component Object Model (COM), COM should be
>   initialized before ShellExecute is called. Some Shell extensions
>   require the COM single-threaded apartment (STA) type. In that case,
>   COM should be initialized as shown here:
>
> ```
> CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED | COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE)
> ```
>
> There are certainly instances where ShellExecute does not use one of
>   these types of Shell extension and those instances would not require
>   COM to be initialized at all. Nonetheless, it is good practice to
>   always initalize COM before using this function.

Without wishing to sound too condescending, one point to take away from this is to make sure that you always read the documentation from top to bottom.